# Connect to Facebook from iPhone app and post to user's wall

Tags: iphone, facebook

1. Within your iPhone app environment be able to connect to Facebook.
2. Then post a comment & a chosen photo to your Facebook newsfeed:

   > [ Comment: "Hey guys check out my photo! ] [Photo: Image appended to comment ]
3. User clicks 'post on wall' and on the user's Facebook news feed, this will appear:

   > [ "Hey guys check out my photo!" ] + [ photo.jpeg ]
4. Then below thier Facebook news feed is automatically generated link to the iTunes store and App website:

   > [ "Hey guys check out my photo!" ] + [ photo.jpeg ] "Photo created at **'Website Link'** - **available at Itunes"**

Answer (score 1):

You'll need Facebook Connect for iPhone (for a start)

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_for_iPhone

I doubt Facebook has the ability to link to your own App (like Twitter does), you could just hard code a link and append to every comment. You should check the FB T's & C's first.

Comment: yeah i've seen it done of the Whrrl APP. geo based commentary to users wall. the link i see they use is somewhere in the effect of:
Comment Post -via Whirl. but not sure if the Whrrl links to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great tutorial on how to do that, plus you can download the source code:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app

But you have to link to photos already online, uploading your own photos isnt that easy.